# Deleting multiple checked items at a time in MFC listview control box

Tags: listview, mfc

I have an MFC listview control box with extended style `LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES`. My Delete button handler code to delete checked items from the listview control box, is shown below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_cList.GetItemCount(); i++)
{    
     // checking for checked items
     BOOL bCheck = m_cList.GetCheck(i);

     if (bCheck != 0)
     {  
         //deleting the  checked items      
         m_cList.DeleteItem(i);
     }
}
```

The problem with my code is, when I click the Delete button it doesn't delete all the checked items at one shot. Instead, one item is deleted from the listview control box at a time. So I need to click the Delete button again and again if I want to delete multiple checked items. Can anyone help me to delete multiple items at one shot with one click of the Delete button.

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issues is that DeleteItem function is changing the indexes of the items, so after the first item is deleted, the index i is no longer valid inside the loop.
A good solution can be iterating the items in reverse order:

```
for (int i = m_cList.GetItemCount()-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        // checking for checked items
        BOOL bCheck = m_cList.GetCheck(i);

        if (bCheck != 0)
        {
            //deleting the  checked items      
            m_cList.DeleteItem(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: For removing things, sometimes I accumulate item indexes on a `std::stack` and after the loop has ended, I delete one by one popping them from the stack, so no problems.